# How to access server side configuration in $log decorator

Tags: angularjs, angular-decorator

I have have the following routing - this is the part of the home (main page) :

```
templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    resolve: {
        myConfig: function (appConfig) {
            return appConfig.retreiveConfig();
        }
    }
```

The flow is as follows, I load configuration from server before the main page loads so I can use it there.

In addition I use `decorator` for the '$log' service,

**Now to the question**: How can I use the configuration loaded in the routing resolve inside my `$log` `decorator` ?

I don't mind to use some default configuration in the decorator until the proper config will arrive from the server.

---

**I can't** seem to find a way to use any service that uses `$http` or `$resource` because of *Circular dependency*

---

**Is there** any way to manually/problematically initialize the decorator **?**

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is implement your `appConfig.retrieveConfig` service method in a way that the config data is cached. Then call the `appConfig.retreiveConfig()` in your decorator also

In decorator then

```
appConfig.retreiveConfig().then(function(data) {
    //Update your decorator configuration
});
```

You `retreiveConfig` should resolve the configuration once, so the service method would look something like

```
var config;
serviceObj.retreiveConfig=function() {
   var defer=$q.defer();
   if(config) { defer.resolve(config);}

   someRemoteCall().then(function(data)) {
       config=data;
       defer,resolve(config);
   }
   return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't use the `appConfig` inside my `$log` decorator because of *Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $browser <- $httpBackend <- $http <- appConfig <- $log <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope*

Comment: Can you show what dependencies are required on appConfig and where are you using `exceptionHandler`

Comment: `myServices.factory('appConfig', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {` and the exceptionhanfler which use the `$log`: `angular.module('myApp').config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', 'stacktrace', function ($log, stacktrace) {`